# How to stop Google Sheets from changing letter O to number 0

Tags: google-sheets

I type `=o51-o50` into a cell.
Google Sheets decides that it would be fun to change the o's into zeros.

How to I make Google Sheets stop that rude behavior?

Comment: Please add more details in order to make this reproducible.

Comment: You might want to check more closely. I doubt that it is changing the letter "o" to a zero. It is more likely that it is capitalising the "o's". The content of the cell is a formula (cell O51 minus cell O50).

Comment: I forgot to check back to this after I solved it. I don't even remember how it was solved, maybe just by refreshing the entire page. Perhaps I should delete this question.